# Unable to load the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Unable to load the Index page 
Do I need to make changes in RouteConfig.cs ??

Index.chtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Employee>
@using MVCDemo.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>
<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (Employee employee in @Model)
    { 
        @Html.ActionLink(employee.Name, "Details", new { id = employee.EmployeeId})
    }

</ul>
</div>
```

EmployeeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCDemo.Models;

namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
            employee.Add(new Employee()
            {
                EmployeeId = 101,
                Name = "John",
                Gender = "Male",
                City = "London"
            });

            employee.Add(new Employee()
            {
                EmployeeId = 102,
                Name = "Kacay",
                Gender = "FeMale",
                City = "Floria"
            });

            employee.Add(new Employee()
            {
                EmployeeId = 103,
                Name = "Sasha",
                Gender = "FeMale",
                City = "USA"
            });

            return View(employee);
        }

        public ActionResult Details()
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee()
            {
                EmployeeId = 101,
                Name = "John",
                Gender = "Male",
                City = "London"
            };

            return View(employee);
        }

    }
}
```

Details.chtml

```
@model MVCDemo.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<tr>
    <td>
        EmployeeId : 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.EmployeeId
    </td>
    <td>
        Name : 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Name
    </td>
    <td>
        Gender : 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Gender
    </td>
    <td>
        City : 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.City
    </td>
</tr>
```

Employee.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unable to load the Index page 
Do I need to make changes in RouteConfig.cs ??

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to load it?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a default route config which should handle this.  Make sure the Index.html is set in the correct folder structure.  By convention MVC will look for views in certain directories.  In your case it's probably Views\Employee\Index.html

You can also install the NuGet package Glimpse, which will give insight into what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You index code needs some tweaking.
Try this instead for the index page:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Employee>
@using MVCDemo.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div>
<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeId})
    }
</ul>
</div>
```